# Populating an array with bytes from a string of numbers

Tags: java, arrays, int, byte, populate

I'm trying to populate an array of bytes from a string that contains numbers(some being 2 digits) with spaces in between. I know there is an parseByte function but I'm unsure how to use that when populating an array as it seems to just take the string as one whole number.

my not-working-code:

```
public static void popArray(byte[][] array, String numbers)  
{  
    int counter = 0;        //counter to track position in string of data  
    for(int i=0; i<20; i++)         //cycle rows  
    {  
        for(int y=0; y<20; y++) //cycle columns  
        {  
        array[i][y] = (byte)(Character.digit(.charAt(counter), 10));    
        counter++;    //increase place in data string                                
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Can u explain the if the input is ABCDEF... then what will be the array of byte value regarding the indexs

Comment: the input would be like this 8 78 90 79 4 2 23 3 ... etc

Comment: u r using 2D array so what will be [0][0],[0][1]... value

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain properly. The numbers I want to populate it with are supposed to be in a 20 x 20 square form, that is why I want a 2d array so I don't lose which number is in which row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the string at spaces, then iterate over the resulting array:

```
String[] parts = numbers.split("\\s+");
int counter = 0;                    //counter to track position in string of data  
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {      //cycle rows  
    for (int y = 0; y < 20; y++) {  //cycle columns  
      String s = parts[counter];
      byte b = (byte)(Integer.parseInt())
      array[i][y] = b;    
      counter++;    //increase place in data string                                
    }  
}
```

Comment: This gives me an array out of bounds exception. Just to clarify, `String[] arr = numbers.split("\\s+");` fills the array arr where each element is a number from my input?

Comment: Yes. Could it be that `numbers` contains fewer than 20x20 (=400) numbers? I have changed the code to have each array access on a different line, so it's easier to debug.

Comment: The original data is definitely 20 x 20, however I'm somewhat apprehensive to count through them all in the string to check that. On a happy coincidence by restricting the program to populate only the first 100 elements it managed to spit out the answer I was looking for anyway.

Comment: I know why it there was less. When I've concatinated the string together I haven't added a space between the last number of a line and the first number of the next line. Silly me. Thanks for the answer!